# Conditional Statement On Pandas Dataframe When Column Values Meet A Specific Sequence

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have a dataframe like this

```
   Placement  Value  Order
0   high       10      1
1   med         5      2
2   high        9      3
3   low         3      4
4   med         7      5
5   low         2      6
6   med         6      7
7   high        9      8
8   med         4      9
9   low         2      10
10  high        8      11
11  med         6      12
12  high        8      13
13  med         5      14
14  low         1      15
```

When a "Placement" sequence of "high -> low," "low -> high," "high -> med -> low," or "low -> med -> high" is encountered, I want to find the difference in value between the "high" and "low" of the sequence, adding it as a value in a new "Diff" column for the last row in the sequence. As well, I'd like to have another column, "Measured From," that takes the "Order" value from the first row in the sequence. I would then drop all the rows that don't have a value for the new columns, resulting in a dataframe like

```
   Placement  Value  Order  Diff  Measured From
3   low         3     4      -6      3
7   high        9     8      7       6
9   low         2     10     -7      8
10  high        8     11     6       10
14  low         1     15     -7      13
```

I imagined a way to do it by looking at the previous two "Placement" values for each row, but I read that iteration should be avoided when using Pandas. Is there a more efficient way to find these patterns and do the calculation?

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
out = (df[df['Placement'].ne('med')]
       .assign(Diff=lambda x: x['Value'].diff(), 
               Measured_From=lambda x: x['Order'].shift()
              )[lambda x: x['Placement'].ne(x['Placement'].shift())]
       .dropna(subset='Measured_From'))
```

out

```
   Placement  Value  Order  Diff  Measured_From
3        low      3      4  -6.0              3
7       high      9      8   7.0              6
9        low      2     10  -7.0              8
10      high      8     11   6.0             10
14       low      1     15  -7.0             13
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution - create 3 boolean mask (that you will use to filter the dataframe) and shift those mask as needed. Then concatenate the various dataframes together:

```py
def get_frame(m, nshift):
    x = df.loc[m.shift(nshift, fill_value=False), ["Placement", "Value", "Order"]]
    x["Diff"] = x["Value"] - df.loc[m, "Value"].values
    x["Measured From"] = df.loc[m, "Order"].values
    return x


l, m, h = (
    df["Placement"].eq("low"),
    df["Placement"].eq("med"),
    df["Placement"].eq("high"),
)

m1 = l & h.shift(-1)
m2 = h & l.shift(-1)
m3 = l & m.shift(-1) & h.shift(-2)
m4 = h & m.shift(-1) & l.shift(-2)

out = pd.concat(
    [get_frame(m1, 1), get_frame(m2, 1), get_frame(m3, 2), get_frame(m4, 2)]
).sort_index()

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   Placement  Value  Order  Diff  Measured From
3        low      3      4    -6              3
7       high      9      8     7              6
9        low      2     10    -7              8
10      high      8     11     6             10
14       low      1     15    -7             13
```