# Finding Sequences In Column Values of Pandas Dataframe Groups and Doing Calculations Between A Row Of Each Group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe like this, where each group contains a set of consecutive rows with the same "Placement" value. The Placement values are low->lowmed->highmed->high, and no two consecutive groups will ever have the same Placement value.

```
   Placement  Value  Order  Group
0   high       10      1      1
1   high        8      2      1
2   high        9      3      1
3   highmed     7      4      2
4   highmed     6      5      2
5   lowmed      4      6      3
6   low         1      7      4
7   low         2      8      4
8   lowmed      4      9      5
9   lowmed      5      10     5
10  highmed     7      11     6
11  lowmed      5      12     7
12  high        8      13     8
13  highmed     5      14     9
14  low         1      15     10
```

I want to find points where the Placement value of the groups changes by two placements or more, up or down and uninterrupted, and then find the difference in value between the last row of the first group and first row of the second group. I would then record the first row of the second group in another dataframe, with the difference calculated and order value from the last row of the first group as two new columns.  The resulting dataframe would be something like

```
   Placement  Value  Order  Group  Diff  Measured_From
5   lowmed      4      6      3     5          2
6   low         1      7      4     5          4
6   low         1      7      4     8          2
10  highmed     7      11     6     5          7
12  high        8      13     8     3          11
14  low         1      15     10    4          13
14  low         1      15     10    7          12
```

Logically, the way I'd imagine accomplishing this is by changing the placement values to numerical ones, and checking the 3 groups that precede the current group being looked at.

If we say the group we are currently looking at is group N, then group N-1 would first be checked, and if it has a placement difference of 2 or 3 compared to group N, then the calculation would be conducted and the data would be added to the new dataframe. Then, group N-2 would be checked, and if the placement value difference is less than that of group N-1, or the placement value started moving in the opposite direction of the previous one, we would stop and make group N+1 the new group N. The same logic would apply if group N-3 were checked after group N-2.

I was originally using a code snippet from [another question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78183673/conditional-statement-on-pandas-dataframe-when-column-values-meet-a-specific-seq/78183734#78183734), but since I now have one more placement value and more rows per group, the exact logic can't be applied.

I'm also not sure my idea would be the most efficient, so please feel free to offer better solutions!